# Formatting comments in annotations with eclipse.jdt

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, eclipse-jdt

I am using org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter to format Java code.
I have problem with one case:
For example before formatting I have such

```
@Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME",
       // <tag>
            unique = true
       // </tag>
    )
```

After format unfortunately it looks much worse:

```
@Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME",
            // <tag>
            unique = true
    // </tag>
    )
```

As you can see first comment is shifted a bit. How can I configure it, to not do that?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens when you use `/** TEXT */`?

Comment: Actually in my case it won't happen, so didn't try

Comment: What is the purpose of the second comment? If anything you want to state about `unique = true` could be written in the first comment, then the second comment could be omitted and the default formatting would look fine in my opinion.

Comment: I edited it a bit, those are tags which can contain some informations (needed by our analyzer). Here it is not possible to change place of unique attribute

Comment: It is recommended having comments before the code rather than after the code. So a line comment in a separate line refers to the code after, not to the code before it. That's why I guess that this is hard-coded in the built-in Java formatter and cannot be changed without changing the formatter (Eclipse provides an extension point for Java formatter, so additional Java formatter can be installed as plugins).